# strange issue with css variables and clamp css function

Tags: css, css-variables, css-functions

I am having trouble seeing why the following CSS code involving custom css variables fails to work as expected:

html

```
<ul class="grid">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.grid > *:nth-child(2n) {
    border-right-width: calc((1 - abs(clamp(-1, var(--columns, 1) - 2, 1))) * 5px);
}
.grid {
    --column-gap: 10px;
    --row-gap: 20px;
    --columns: 5;
}
```

Output:

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foo123/xvf1humk/9/)

The problem is that every `2n` item has a right border width, when by calculation the `border-right-width` **should be zero** (since `--columns` has a value other than `2` and `1 - abs(clamp(-1, var(--columns, 1) - 2, 1))` should evaluate to `0`).

What am I missing? And how can the `border-right-width` calculation activate only when `--columns` takes the value of 2 and not otherwise (otherwise 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now `abs()` is [only supported by Firefox and Safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_abs). Change `abs(x)` to `max(x, 0 - x)`

```css
.grid>*:nth-child(2n) {
  border-right-width: calc((1 - max(clamp(-1, var(--columns, 1) - 2, 1),
     0 - clamp(-1, var(--columns, 1) - 2, 1))) * 5px);
}
```

Comment: Firefox also produces unexpected output even though it is supposed to support `abs` (chrome also fails but differently). Nevertheless I will try the `max` alternative and see.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the border-right-width is only applied when --columns is exactly 2, you need to adjust your calculation. You can use a simpler check:

```
.grid > *:nth-child(2n) {
border-right-width: calc((var(--columns, 1) == 2) * 5px);
```

}

However, the equality check `(==)` is not supported in CSS `calc()`. As a workaround, you could use JavaScript to dynamically add a class or inline style based on the value of `--columns`.

If you want a pure CSS solution, check below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="grid" data-columns="5">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.grid > li {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

/* Apply specific styles when --columns is 2 */
.grid[data-columns="2"] > li:nth-child(2n) {
    border-right-width: 5px;
}

.grid {
    --column-gap: 10px;
    --row-gap: 20px;
    --columns: 5;
}
```

Here, you manually set the data-columns attribute in your HTML to match the `--columns` value. Then, you use this attribute in your CSS to selectively apply styles. This method requires updating the HTML whenever you change the `--columns` value.

Comment: yes using js or data properties would work but I do not want that. Why do you think the `clamp` calculation fails when it should produce correct result in theory?